# echo variable misbehaving in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

my code (call it infiniteping) echoes beginning and when state of ping changes

```
@echo off

rem set details=""

set arg1=%1
set history="none"
set current_status="none"
Set COUNTER=0
:loop
set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
ping -n 1 %arg1% | find /i "reply" > log.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
set /p details=<log.txt
set current_status="yes"
echo %current_status%
)
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
set current_status="no"
echo %current_status%
)
if %history% equ "none" (
echo %COUNTER%
echo %time%
if %current_status% equ "yes" (
echo %details%
)
if %current_status% equ "no" (
echo can't ping %arg1%
)
echo.
)
if %history% equ "yes" if %current_status% equ "no" (
echo %COUNTER%
echo %time%
echo can't ping %arg1%
echo.
)
if %history% equ "no" if %current_status% equ "yes" (
echo %COUNTER%
echo %time%
echo %details%
echo.
)
set "history=%current_status%"
rem echo history=%history%
sleep 1
goto loop

[/code]
```

I am using external file sleep.exe to check after 1 second.

Here is the output when I pass an active IP and an inactive IP as the only parameter to infiniteping one by one

```
C:\Users\si>infiniteping 172.16.92.1
"none"
1
17:32:30.84
Reply from 172.16.92.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

"yes"
"yes"
"yes"
"yes"
"yes"
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y



C:\Users\si>infiniteping 172.16.92.100
"none"
1
17:33:02.58
can't ping 172.16.92.100

"no"
"no"
```

I can't understand its reason for echoing "none" instead of yes or no at first ?

Comment: Of use to you might be the -t switch for ping. You can use that to run ping for hours and redirect the output to a text file. I've used this to track down flaky cables and network cards/ports.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

rem set details=""

set arg1=%1
set history="none"
set current_status="none"
Set COUNTER=0
:loop
set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
ping -n 1 %arg1% | find /i "reply" > log.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
set /p details=<log.txt
set current_status="yes"
)
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
set current_status="no"
)
echo %current_status%
```

...

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

In your case, `current_status` is set within the parentheses, hence the *previous* value will be displayed. With the changes, the value is displayed *after* the parentheses, hence the *new* value will be displayed.

Please see any number of articles on SO about `delayedexpansion`